# fields for child_index not changing for nested_attributes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using nested_attributes for has many associations. The nested attributed is added dynamically.

The association is Invoice has_many Items

Contoller code:

```
def new
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  @invoice.items.build    
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invoice,:format => :js,:method => :post, :post => true,:url => invoices_path, :required => true) do |f|%>
   <%= f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.text_field :fullname %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.text_field :fullname %>
   <% end %>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#btnAddItemtoInvoice').on('click', function(){ 
            $('.exp').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item_fields.html.erb', locals: {f: f}) %>")
         })
   </script>
 <% end %>
```

**For first two row the child index is incremented properly but for rows from partials are not incremented. Child index I am getting is: 0,1,2,2,2 and so on.**

Partial: _item_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :fullname %>
<% end %>
```

Why the child_index are not incrementing? How can I increment the child_index here?

Comment: i think that in the way you are using the partial is generated once, and then used every time. try using on click to first request a new invoice from server and then create its HTML and append it.

Comment: I do not want to hit server to just add a new row

Comment: then you can exclude id from fields and only create it on save, then when you append you will not have id at all - the server will generate it only when it gets the data to save